# Spring Batch AbstractPagingItemReader stop when result size id less than ITEMS_BY_PAGE

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-batch, paging

I've add AbstractPagingItemReader to read by packet from api by 100 items

The execution is OK until the size of returned items is less than 100

Here is my code :

```
    public static final int ITEMS_BY_PAGE = 10;

@Override
protected void doReadPage() {
    setPageSize(ITEMS_BY_PAGE);
    results = this.documentService.searchRecordsWithAwaitingDocument(getPage(), ITEMS_BY_PAGE);
}

@Override
protected void doJumpToPage(int itemIndex) {

}
```

Is there a way to not stop the execution when the size of returned items is less than ITEMS_BY_PAGE ? i want to stop the execution only when there is no result on return (size 0) ?

Comment: No, as a page size less then the configured size means it it the end (else there would be the same as the page size and a potential next page). That is the whole point of paging, feels like you are using the wrong tool for the job. Don't use the paging one and implement the logic yourself to stop at 0.

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement pagination logic outside the batch and i'll just use ItemReader

Comment: You an still paginate in your reader, but instead of stopping at the point where the page size is smaller then configured, continue until you read get 0 items. You probably still want to chunk the retrieval, at least that is what it appears you are doing. It is more of a max-results per poll instead of paging you want and you tried to shoehorn that into paging.

Comment: I dont find a doc how to do this with pagination

Comment: You don't as I explained twice before.